# Cannot do this - import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am really sorry but i am new to angular and have been following a video tutorial, i seem to have done every thing right but when i added bootstrap as required the

npm install ngx-bootstrap bootstrap --save

then

```
open src/app/app.module.ts and add

import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

and also added--

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AlertModule
  ],
```

also adding with style----

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
```

For the whole day i have been trying but keep getting  this error -

ERROR in D:/ng-gallery/gallery/src/app/app.module.ts (6,29): Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap'.

```
enter code here
```

Can any one please guide me ...

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You will need bootstrap styles (Bootstrap 3)

```
<!-- index.html -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or Bootstrap 4

```
<!--- index.html -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

To enable bootstrap 4 theme templates in ngx-bootstrap, please read
[here](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/bootstrap4.md)

open `src/app/app.module.ts` and add

```
import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';...
@NgModule({
...
imports: [AlertModule.forRoot(), ... ],
... 
})
```

open `.angular-cli.json` and insert a new entry into the styles array

```
"styles": [
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
"styles.css",
],
```

open `src/app/app.component.html` and add

`<alert type="success">hello</alert>`

Comment: Sir ,  i have tried this as well but when i add - import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap'; , there is a red line below ngx-bootstrap and some how it seems its not getting detected , i have added bootstrap can also see its version , but still not woking , thanks again ...

Comment: try `npm install ngx-bootstrap --save` and reload your IDE or text editor

Comment: Thank you very much sir ,  i was installing it in wrong folder now the webpack compiles , but i am getting some warnings  like - WARNING in Circular dependency detected:app\ngx-bootstrap\modal\bs-modal.service.js -> app\ngx-bootstrap\modal\modal-container.component.js -> app\ngx-bootstrap\modal\bs-
modal.service.js , will my project work with these warnings...

Comment: available. If you can mark the answer, I'm grateful.

Comment: It seems you now need `import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/alert';`

Answer (score 1):

Simply write in app.modules.ts

import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/alert';

write "/alert" at the end and see the result

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.